# What does the "+" symbol mean on the left side of the R console?

Tags: r, console, symbols

I have entered in code to plot a graph, but when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute the graph, it does not plot the graph. Rather, `+` symbols appear every time I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute the command and plot the code.
Now there is a long column of `+` symbols in my R consoles.

Why is this happening and what can I do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: If you show the code you're typing, people can probably spot where you have failed to close a pair of parentheses, quotes etc

Answer (score 17):

The prompt has `+` because it signifies that the prompt is expecting more from the line of code, a sort of continuation. This may be because you forgot to close something so the prompt expects the closing side. For example, say you forgot to close a string like so:

```
> "
+
+
```

Here, I entered a double-quote into the prompt and kept on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. There is a missing double-quote to tell the prompt I've ended the string literal, so the prompt expects another double-quote. Once you enter the double quote the prompt will stop expecting it. For example:

```
> "
+
+ "
[1] "\n\n"
```

This is standard on all command prompts, to expect more code if something isn't ended properly, like the string literal above. Check your code to make sure you've closed all opening quotes, symbols, etc, so the prompt doesn't expect it and your code executes correctly.

The ways of exiting the prompt when this happens are:

- <kbd>Esc</kbd> on RGui and RStudio
- <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> on Terminals and Command Prompts

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if you used space in the middle of an object name, eg. Column names. R doesn't allow space in between " ".